# Performing data binding during ajax-request

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have the following markup:

```
<rich:panel id="selectorPanel">
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.field1}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.field2}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.field3}" />
    <!-- and so forth -->
    <h:selectOneMenu id="selector" value="#{myBean.selected}">
        <a4j:ajax event="change" listener="#{myBean.doUpdateValues()}" render="selectorPanel" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{msgs['bundle.addFilter']}" itemValue="#{null}" value="#{null}"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.filters}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</rich:panel>
```

***The problem***: when I change the value of the `selectOneMenu` the `selectorPanel` is being rerendered, therefore the values of the `inputText`s  are being refreshed and set to the `myBean`'s properties value.

But I need to set values entered by user on the web-page to the corresponding bean's properties before rerendering.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

Why to do need to execute all? the @form should be enough or even list of inputs ids.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution just now and we can actually use [execute](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest/vdldoc/a4j/ajax.html#execute) attribute as follows:

```
execute="@all"
```

It works for me.

Comment: `execute="@all"` is a bad practice. It is just like sending a synchronous request even thought it looks like an asynchronous request. Avoid it.

Comment: @Tiny So what would you propose to solve that problem?

Comment: @Tiny BTW, f:ajax tag doesn't have such an attribute. Is there something similar in JSF 2.1 out of the box?

Comment: It is fully transparently dependent upon the specific business requirements. You can, if necessary, specify a list of required components to be executed/processed. If you need to execute/process the whole form, you can specify `@form` - if none to be executed, then `@none` and alike. `<f:ajax execute="..." render="..." .../>` is available in JSF 2.1, by the way - I can remember, when I was using JSF 2.1 in the past :)

Comment: @Tiny Good explanation, thank you. Why don't you post your comment as an answer? I think someone else might find it useful too.